# Specific use of Present Continuous

Tags: present-progressive

Could anyone please clarify this specific use of the Present Continuous for me? The following two excerpts are taken from movies:

1) Malcolm in the Middle

*He's giving that same lecture to younger classmen. I can't let that happen. **I'm stealing** his slides.*

2) Groundhog Day

[Phil has been brought to a hotel by his manager]

*Phil: I hate this place. I stayed here two years ago. I was miserable. It's a fleabag. **I'm not staying** here.*

This doesn't seem to me like a future arrangement. It's more likely a spontaneous decision. Shouldn't Future Simple be used there instead: *I will steal his slides; I will not stay here*.

Comment: Please, before marking as potential duplicate, notice that the question isn’t really talking about a *future action* in the sense of *next week* as the related question on the right is giving examples for. It’s not really a future action at all, in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the present tense is associated with an announcement of intent, is confusing to people learning the language, defies analysis with the simple tools taught to beginners, and is idiomatic in both American and British Englishes.

The first form is a statement that, in effect, *“I **am now executing a plan to** steal his slides”*. It’s effective because it’s a statement of intent, with *immediacy* ­— they are going to steal those slides *right now*, or at least as soon as they can. It reflects the thought process of the person, where — in their mind at least — *the stated action has already begun*.

The second can be interpreted ***as of now, my being here is only temporary***. Really there’s nothing surprising: a question-and-answer might go —

> Are you here for the night?
>   Yes, I’m staying here.

where the action has already begun (he’s been *staying* since he arrived, and will be until he leaves).

In your example, Phil is simply stating the opposite —

> *No, I'm not staying here. I’m only here until you arrange something different or I leave to look for somewhere else.*

In other words, neither of these cases is really about a *future* action at all, at least not in the sense of “planning” to do something.

Comment: I disagree. 'I'm stealing his slides' does not express intent, it expresses an action, but _the activity of stealing_ is future. It is not yet happening. Likewise 'I'm not staying here' expresses a future event, because at the moment _he is here_. These two examples are very cleverly chosen to illustrate the OP's point.

Comment: If you say "I'm staying" when you're already there, it's an action that's *already in progress*, that was my point ...

Comment: @NigelJ OPs point was that he thought the tense was wrong because it *“doesn't seem to me like a future arrangement”*, and I think in these particular cases that’s true; that both do indeed represent *“a spontaneous decision”* as they put it.

Comment: @NigelJ in 99%+ of cases, I agree that *I'm --ing* is a periphrastic future tense, FWIW. Even in this case you *could* argue there's an elided periphrasis; I don't deny that :)